# Reading and writing from a single serial port simultaneously from multiple threads

Tags: multithreading, python-2.7, serialization, subprocess

I have a serial port which gives me a lot of different data from different pieces of hardware. I need to send different commands to the serial port to receive different kinds of data from it. So, I need to write and read data simultaneously from the port in different functions. Sometimes, I might need to read and write simultaneously from the serial port  in 10 different threads. What is the best way of writing code in this situation for simultaneously reading/writing data from a single port? Threads, sub processes, etc.

Comment: "best" as usual depends on many things. You could start with two queues (input and output). If the serial port writes a single byte; what do you want to happen then 10 threads try to read it?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian No. Actually each thread needs to send a different command to the serial port and in turn read immediately after writing to it.

Comment: and how does it relate to my comment? Each thread is free to put  whatever it likes to the output queue. Again, how do you know which thread should receive an answer? (does response always contain an id of the corresponding request? Do all responses arrive in order? Can you send the next request without waiting for the response to a previous request?)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian sorry.There is a controller connected at the other end of the serial port. DMA and FIFO are implemented in the controller, and it can handle multiple requests. There is a protocol implemented for communication which has a key and data field. So as per the protocol, one thread from python sends a command to serial port with key set to a particular value and gets response from the controller in return corresponding to the key.  Second thread sends  another command with a different key for which it gets its response corresponding to its key. And so on for 10 threads.

Comment: Do the responses contain the key they correspond to?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Yes, they do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with the most straightforward code that works in your case. If your script already starts multiple threads then you could add reader/writer threads that communicate with the controller -- all other threads send/receive data only from these threads: `send_queue` consumed by the writer thread is used to send commands to the controller and each worker thread has its own `receive_queue` populated by the reader thread:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
"""Communicate with a dummy controller from 10 worker threads.

- start controller subprocess, worker threads
- send all requests and check responses in worker threads concurrently
- wait until all responses are received
"""
import json
import logging
import sys
from Queue import Queue
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
from threading import Thread

log = logging.getLogger(__name__).debug

def worker(tid, send_queue, receive_queue):
    """Send some dummy requests, get responses."""
    log('starting worker tid=%s', tid)
    for i in range(5):
        log('sending request key=%s, data=%d', tid, i)
        send_queue.put(dict(key=tid, data=i)) # send request
        response = receive_queue.get() # get response
        # check response
        log('got response %s, key=%s, data=%d', response, tid, i)
        assert response['key'] == tid and response['data'] == i**2

def reader(pipe, thread_queues):
    """Read responses from the controller (*pipe*).

       Dispatch them to the corresponding threads.
    """
    log('starting reader')
    with pipe:
        for line in iter(pipe.readline, b''): # read response from the controller
            log('got line %r', line)
            response = json.loads(line)
            # dispatch to the corresponding thread
            thread_queues[response['key']].put(response)

def writer(pipe, send_queue):
    """Write requests to the controller (*pipe*) from *send_queue*."""
    log('starting writer')
    with pipe:
        for request in iter(send_queue.get, None):
            log('sending request %s', request)
            print >>pipe, json.dumps(request)

def start_daemon_thread(*args, **kwargs):
    """Start and return daemonic thread."""
    t = Thread(*args, **kwargs)
    t.daemon = True # die with the program
    t.start()
    return t

def main():
    nthreads = 10
    timeout = 1 # seconds, for Ctrl+C
    logging.basicConfig(format="%(asctime)-15s %(threadName)s %(message)s",
                        datefmt='%F %T', level=logging.DEBUG)
    # start controller
    controller = Popen([sys.executable, "-u", "dummy_controller.py"],
                       stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, bufsize=1)
    # start threads
    send_queue = Queue(maxsize=50) # limit number of queued requests (backlog)
    thread_queues = {tid: Queue() for tid in range(1, nthreads + 1)}
    threads = [start_daemon_thread(name='worker-' + str(tid),
                                   target=worker, args=[tid, send_queue, q])
               for tid, q in thread_queues.items()]

    # read/write until there are requests
    start_daemon_thread(name='writer', target=writer,
                        args=[controller.stdin, send_queue])
    log('about to start a reader')
    reader_thread = start_daemon_thread(name='reader', target=reader,
                                        args=[controller.stdout, thread_queues])
    # wait until workers are done
    while threads:
        for t in threads:
            t.join(timeout) # workaround, enable Ctrl+C on Python 2.7
            if not t.is_alive():
                threads.remove(t)
                break
    log('no worker threads')
    send_queue.put(None) # no more requests
    # wait until all responses are received
    while reader_thread.is_alive():
        reader_thread.join(timeout) # workaround, enable Ctrl+C on Python 2.7
    controller.wait() # wait for the subprocess to exit (to avoid zombies)
    log('done')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

where `dummy_controller.py` is a simple script that computes `x**2` for each input `x`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
"""Dummy controller."""
import json
import sys

for line in iter(sys.stdin.readline, b''):
    request = json.loads(line)
    # square data field in the request and send it back
    print json.dumps(dict(request, data=int(request['data'])**2))
```

Your code don't need a subprocess, you should call the appropriate read/write methods for the serial port instead of starting a subprocess and using pipes.

The code is verbose and it is not optimized for speed. If your worker threads are CPU-bound then you should find a way to release GIL (e.g., on CPython implementation): C extensions or offload the work to a process pool; otherwise only one CPU core is used by python implementation with GIL (CPython, Pypy (default)).

#### Example Output

```
2015-09-27 20:02:38 worker-1 starting worker tid=1
2015-09-27 20:02:38 worker-1 sending request key=1, data=0
2015-09-27 20:02:38 worker-2 starting worker tid=2
2015-09-27 20:02:38 worker-3 starting worker tid=3
2015-09-27 20:02:38 worker-3 sending request key=3, data=0
2015-09-27 20:02:38 worker-2 sending request key=2, data=0
2015-09-27 20:02:38 worker-5 starting worker tid=5
2015-09-27 20:02:38 worker-4 starting worker tid=4
2015-09-27 20:02:38 worker-6 starting worker tid=6
2015-09-27 20:02:38 worker-7 starting worker tid=7
2015-09-27 20:02:38 worker-5 sending request key=5, data=0
2015-09-27 20:02:38 worker-6 sending request key=6, data=0
2015-09-27 20:02:38 worker-4 sending request key=4, data=0
2015-09-27 20:02:38 worker-8 starting worker tid=8
2015-09-27 20:02:38 worker-7 sending request key=7, data=0
2015-09-27 20:02:38 worker-9 starting worker tid=9
2015-09-27 20:02:38 worker-8 sending request key=8, data=0
2015-09-27 20:02:38 worker-9 sending request key=9, data=0
2015-09-27 20:02:38 worker-10 starting worker tid=10
2015-09-27 20:02:38 worker-10 sending request key=10, data=0
2015-09-27 20:02:38 MainThread about to start a reader
2015-09-27 20:02:38 writer starting writer
2015-09-27 20:02:38 reader starting reader
2015-09-27 20:02:38 writer sending request {'data': 0, 'key': 1}
2015-09-27 20:02:38 writer sending request {'data': 0, 'key': 3}
2015-09-27 20:02:38 writer sending request {'data': 0, 'key': 2}
2015-09-27 20:02:38 writer sending request {'data': 0, 'key': 5}
2015-09-27 20:02:38 writer sending request {'data': 0, 'key': 6}
2015-09-27 20:02:38 writer sending request {'data': 0, 'key': 4}
2015-09-27 20:02:38 writer sending request {'data': 0, 'key': 7}
2015-09-27 20:02:38 writer sending request {'data': 0, 'key': 8}
2015-09-27 20:02:38 writer sending request {'data': 0, 'key': 9}
2015-09-27 20:02:38 writer sending request {'data': 0, 'key': 10}
2015-09-27 20:02:38 reader got line '{"data": 0, "key": 1}\n'
2015-09-27 20:02:38 reader got line '{"data": 0, "key": 3}\n'
2015-09-27 20:02:38 worker-1 got response {u'data': 0, u'key': 1}, key=1, data=0
2015-09-27 20:02:38 reader got line '{"data": 0, "key": 2}\n'
2015-09-27 20:02:38 worker-3 got response {u'data': 0, u'key': 3}, key=3, data=0
2015-09-27 20:02:38 worker-1 sending request key=1, data=1
2015-09-27 20:02:38 reader got line '{"data": 0, "key": 5}\n'
2015-09-27 20:02:38 worker-2 got response {u'data': 0, u'key': 2}, key=2, data=0
2015-09-27 20:02:38 worker-3 sending request key=3, data=1
2015-09-27 20:02:38 writer sending request {'data': 1, 'key': 1}
2015-09-27 20:02:38 worker-5 got response {u'data': 0, u'key': 5}, key=5, data=0
2015-09-27 20:02:38 worker-2 sending request key=2, data=1
2015-09-27 20:02:38 reader got line '{"data": 0, "key": 6}\n'
2015-09-27 20:02:38 writer sending request {'data': 1, 'key': 3}
2015-09-27 20:02:38 worker-5 sending request key=5, data=1
2015-09-27 20:02:38 worker-6 got response {u'data': 0, u'key': 6}, key=6, data=0
2015-09-27 20:02:38 reader got line '{"data": 0, "key": 4}\n'
2015-09-27 20:02:38 writer sending request {'data': 1, 'key': 2}
2015-09-27 20:02:38 worker-6 sending request key=6, data=1
2015-09-27 20:02:38 reader got line '{"data": 0, "key": 7}\n'
2015-09-27 20:02:38 worker-4 got response {u'data': 0, u'key': 4}, key=4, data=0
2015-09-27 20:02:38 writer sending request {'data': 1, 'key': 5}
2015-09-27 20:02:38 worker-4 sending request key=4, data=1
2015-09-27 20:02:38 reader got line '{"data": 0, "key": 8}\n'
2015-09-27 20:02:38 writer sending request {'data': 1, 'key': 6}
2015-09-27 20:02:38 worker-7 got response {u'data': 0, u'key': 7}, key=7, data=0
2015-09-27 20:02:38 reader got line '{"data": 0, "key": 9}\n'
2015-09-27 20:02:38 worker-8 got response {u'data': 0, u'key': 8}, key=8, data=0
2015-09-27 20:02:38 writer sending request {'data': 1, 'key': 4}
2015-09-27 20:02:38 worker-7 sending request key=7, data=1
2015-09-27 20:02:38 reader got line '{"data": 0, "key": 10}\n'
2015-09-27 20:02:38 worker-9 got response {u'data': 0, u'key': 9}, key=9, data=0
2015-09-27 20:02:38 worker-8 sending request key=8, data=1
2015-09-27 20:02:38 reader got line '{"data": 1, "key": 1}\n'
2015-09-27 20:02:38 writer sending request {'data': 1, 'key': 7}
2015-09-27 20:02:38 worker-10 got response {u'data': 0, u'key': 10}, key=10, data=0
2015-09-27 20:02:38 worker-9 sending request key=9, data=1
2015-09-27 20:02:38 reader got line '{"data": 1, "key": 3}\n'
2015-09-27 20:02:38 writer sending request {'data': 1, 'key': 8}
2015-09-27 20:02:38 worker-1 got response {u'data': 1, u'key': 1}, key=1, data=1
2015-09-27 20:02:38 worker-10 sending request key=10, data=1
2015-09-27 20:02:38 worker-3 got response {u'data': 1, u'key': 3}, key=3, data=1
2015-09-27 20:02:38 reader got line '{"data": 1, "key": 2}\n'
2015-09-27 20:02:38 writer sending request {'data': 1, 'key': 9}
2015-09-27 20:02:38 worker-1 sending request key=1, data=2
2015-09-27 20:02:38 worker-3 sending request key=3, data=2
2015-09-27 20:02:38 worker-2 got response {u'data': 1, u'key': 2}, key=2, data=1
2015-09-27 20:02:38 reader got line '{"data": 1, "key": 5}\n'
2015-09-27 20:02:38 writer sending request {'data': 1, 'key': 10}
2015-09-27 20:02:38 worker-2 sending request key=2, data=2
2015-09-27 20:02:38 worker-5 got response {u'data': 1, u'key': 5}, key=5, data=1
2015-09-27 20:02:38 reader got line '{"data": 1, "key": 6}\n'
2015-09-27 20:02:38 writer sending request {'data': 2, 'key': 1}
2015-09-27 20:02:38 worker-5 sending request key=5, data=2
2015-09-27 20:02:38 reader got line '{"data": 1, "key": 4}\n'
2015-09-27 20:02:38 worker-6 got response {u'data': 1, u'key': 6}, key=6, data=1
2015-09-27 20:02:38 writer sending request {'data': 2, 'key': 3}
2015-09-27 20:02:38 worker-4 got response {u'data': 1, u'key': 4}, key=4, data=1
2015-09-27 20:02:38 reader got line '{"data": 1, "key": 7}\n'
2015-09-27 20:02:38 worker-6 sending request key=6, data=2
2015-09-27 20:02:38 writer sending request {'data': 2, 'key': 2}
2015-09-27 20:02:38 worker-4 sending request key=4, data=2
2015-09-27 20:02:38 worker-7 got response {u'data': 1, u'key': 7}, key=7, data=1
2015-09-27 20:02:38 reader got line '{"data": 1, "key": 8}\n'
2015-09-27 20:02:38 worker-7 sending request key=7, data=2
2015-09-27 20:02:38 writer sending request {'data': 2, 'key': 5}
2015-09-27 20:02:38 reader got line '{"data": 1, "key": 9}\n'
2015-09-27 20:02:38 worker-8 got response {u'data': 1, u'key': 8}, key=8, data=1
2015-09-27 20:02:38 reader got line '{"data": 1, "key": 10}\n'
2015-09-27 20:02:38 worker-8 sending request key=8, data=2
2015-09-27 20:02:38 worker-9 got response {u'data': 1, u'key': 9}, key=9, data=1
2015-09-27 20:02:38 writer sending request {'data': 2, 'key': 6}
2015-09-27 20:02:38 reader got line '{"data": 4, "key": 1}\n'
2015-09-27 20:02:38 worker-10 got response {u'data': 1, u'key': 10}, key=10, data=1
2015-09-27 20:02:38 worker-9 sending request key=9, data=2
2015-09-27 20:02:38 writer sending request {'data': 2, 'key': 4}
2015-09-27 20:02:38 worker-1 got response {u'data': 4, u'key': 1}, key=1, data=2
2015-09-27 20:02:38 reader got line '{"data": 4, "key": 3}\n'
2015-09-27 20:02:38 worker-10 sending request key=10, data=2
2015-09-27 20:02:38 writer sending request {'data': 2, 'key': 7}
2015-09-27 20:02:38 worker-1 sending request key=1, data=3
2015-09-27 20:02:38 worker-3 got response {u'data': 4, u'key': 3}, key=3, data=2
2015-09-27 20:02:38 reader got line '{"data": 4, "key": 2}\n'
2015-09-27 20:02:38 writer sending request {'data': 2, 'key': 8}
2015-09-27 20:02:38 worker-3 sending request key=3, data=3
2015-09-27 20:02:38 worker-2 got response {u'data': 4, u'key': 2}, key=2, data=2
2015-09-27 20:02:38 reader got line '{"data": 4, "key": 5}\n'
2015-09-27 20:02:38 writer sending request {'data': 2, 'key': 9}
2015-09-27 20:02:38 worker-2 sending request key=2, data=3
2015-09-27 20:02:38 reader got line '{"data": 4, "key": 6}\n'
2015-09-27 20:02:38 writer sending request {'data': 2, 'key': 10}
2015-09-27 20:02:38 worker-5 got response {u'data': 4, u'key': 5}, key=5, data=2
2015-09-27 20:02:38 reader got line '{"data": 4, "key": 4}\n'
2015-09-27 20:02:38 worker-6 got response {u'data': 4, u'key': 6}, key=6, data=2
2015-09-27 20:02:38 writer sending request {'data': 3, 'key': 1}
2015-09-27 20:02:38 worker-5 sending request key=5, data=3
2015-09-27 20:02:38 reader got line '{"data": 4, "key": 7}\n'
2015-09-27 20:02:38 worker-4 got response {u'data': 4, u'key': 4}, key=4, data=2
2015-09-27 20:02:38 worker-6 sending request key=6, data=3
2015-09-27 20:02:38 writer sending request {'data': 3, 'key': 3}
2015-09-27 20:02:38 reader got line '{"data": 4, "key": 8}\n'
2015-09-27 20:02:38 worker-7 got response {u'data': 4, u'key': 7}, key=7, data=2
2015-09-27 20:02:38 worker-4 sending request key=4, data=3
2015-09-27 20:02:38 writer sending request {'data': 3, 'key': 2}
2015-09-27 20:02:38 reader got line '{"data": 4, "key": 9}\n'
2015-09-27 20:02:38 worker-7 sending request key=7, data=3
2015-09-27 20:02:38 worker-8 got response {u'data': 4, u'key': 8}, key=8, data=2
2015-09-27 20:02:38 writer sending request {'data': 3, 'key': 5}
2015-09-27 20:02:38 worker-9 got response {u'data': 4, u'key': 9}, key=9, data=2
2015-09-27 20:02:38 reader got line '{"data": 4, "key": 10}\n'
2015-09-27 20:02:38 worker-8 sending request key=8, data=3
2015-09-27 20:02:38 writer sending request {'data': 3, 'key': 6}
2015-09-27 20:02:38 worker-9 sending request key=9, data=3
2015-09-27 20:02:38 reader got line '{"data": 9, "key": 1}\n'
2015-09-27 20:02:38 worker-10 got response {u'data': 4, u'key': 10}, key=10, data=2
2015-09-27 20:02:38 writer sending request {'data': 3, 'key': 4}
2015-09-27 20:02:38 reader got line '{"data": 9, "key": 3}\n'
2015-09-27 20:02:38 worker-10 sending request key=10, data=3
2015-09-27 20:02:38 worker-1 got response {u'data': 9, u'key': 1}, key=1, data=3
2015-09-27 20:02:38 writer sending request {'data': 3, 'key': 7}
2015-09-27 20:02:38 reader got line '{"data": 9, "key": 2}\n'
2015-09-27 20:02:38 worker-3 got response {u'data': 9, u'key': 3}, key=3, data=3
2015-09-27 20:02:38 worker-3 sending request key=3, data=4
2015-09-27 20:02:38 writer sending request {'data': 3, 'key': 8}
2015-09-27 20:02:38 reader got line '{"data": 9, "key": 5}\n'
2015-09-27 20:02:38 worker-2 got response {u'data': 9, u'key': 2}, key=2, data=3
2015-09-27 20:02:38 worker-2 sending request key=2, data=4
2015-09-27 20:02:38 writer sending request {'data': 3, 'key': 9}
2015-09-27 20:02:38 reader got line '{"data": 9, "key": 6}\n'
2015-09-27 20:02:38 worker-5 got response {u'data': 9, u'key': 5}, key=5, data=3
2015-09-27 20:02:38 worker-1 sending request key=1, data=4
2015-09-27 20:02:38 writer sending request {'data': 3, 'key': 10}
2015-09-27 20:02:38 worker-6 got response {u'data': 9, u'key': 6}, key=6, data=3
2015-09-27 20:02:38 reader got line '{"data": 9, "key": 4}\n'
2015-09-27 20:02:38 worker-5 sending request key=5, data=4
2015-09-27 20:02:38 writer sending request {'data': 4, 'key': 3}
2015-09-27 20:02:38 worker-6 sending request key=6, data=4
2015-09-27 20:02:38 reader got line '{"data": 9, "key": 7}\n'
2015-09-27 20:02:38 worker-4 got response {u'data': 9, u'key': 4}, key=4, data=3
2015-09-27 20:02:38 writer sending request {'data': 4, 'key': 2}
2015-09-27 20:02:38 worker-7 got response {u'data': 9, u'key': 7}, key=7, data=3
2015-09-27 20:02:38 reader got line '{"data": 9, "key": 8}\n'
2015-09-27 20:02:38 worker-4 sending request key=4, data=4
2015-09-27 20:02:38 writer sending request {'data': 4, 'key': 1}
2015-09-27 20:02:38 worker-7 sending request key=7, data=4
2015-09-27 20:02:38 reader got line '{"data": 9, "key": 9}\n'
2015-09-27 20:02:38 worker-8 got response {u'data': 9, u'key': 8}, key=8, data=3
2015-09-27 20:02:38 writer sending request {'data': 4, 'key': 5}
2015-09-27 20:02:38 reader got line '{"data": 9, "key": 10}\n'
2015-09-27 20:02:38 worker-9 got response {u'data': 9, u'key': 9}, key=9, data=3
2015-09-27 20:02:38 worker-8 sending request key=8, data=4
2015-09-27 20:02:38 writer sending request {'data': 4, 'key': 6}
2015-09-27 20:02:38 reader got line '{"data": 16, "key": 3}\n'
2015-09-27 20:02:38 worker-10 got response {u'data': 9, u'key': 10}, key=10, data=3
2015-09-27 20:02:38 worker-9 sending request key=9, data=4
2015-09-27 20:02:38 writer sending request {'data': 4, 'key': 4}
2015-09-27 20:02:38 reader got line '{"data": 16, "key": 2}\n'
2015-09-27 20:02:38 worker-3 got response {u'data': 16, u'key': 3}, key=3, data=4
2015-09-27 20:02:38 worker-10 sending request key=10, data=4
2015-09-27 20:02:38 writer sending request {'data': 4, 'key': 7}
2015-09-27 20:02:38 worker-2 got response {u'data': 16, u'key': 2}, key=2, data=4
2015-09-27 20:02:38 reader got line '{"data": 16, "key": 1}\n'
2015-09-27 20:02:38 writer sending request {'data': 4, 'key': 8}
2015-09-27 20:02:38 reader got line '{"data": 16, "key": 5}\n'
2015-09-27 20:02:38 writer sending request {'data': 4, 'key': 9}
2015-09-27 20:02:38 reader got line '{"data": 16, "key": 6}\n'
2015-09-27 20:02:38 worker-5 got response {u'data': 16, u'key': 5}, key=5, data=4
2015-09-27 20:02:38 worker-1 got response {u'data': 16, u'key': 1}, key=1, data=4
2015-09-27 20:02:38 writer sending request {'data': 4, 'key': 10}
2015-09-27 20:02:38 worker-6 got response {u'data': 16, u'key': 6}, key=6, data=4
2015-09-27 20:02:38 reader got line '{"data": 16, "key": 4}\n'
2015-09-27 20:02:38 reader got line '{"data": 16, "key": 7}\n'
2015-09-27 20:02:38 worker-4 got response {u'data': 16, u'key': 4}, key=4, data=4
2015-09-27 20:02:38 worker-7 got response {u'data': 16, u'key': 7}, key=7, data=4
2015-09-27 20:02:38 reader got line '{"data": 16, "key": 8}\n'
2015-09-27 20:02:38 reader got line '{"data": 16, "key": 9}\n'
2015-09-27 20:02:38 worker-8 got response {u'data': 16, u'key': 8}, key=8, data=4
2015-09-27 20:02:38 reader got line '{"data": 16, "key": 10}\n'
2015-09-27 20:02:38 worker-9 got response {u'data': 16, u'key': 9}, key=9, data=4
2015-09-27 20:02:38 worker-10 got response {u'data': 16, u'key': 10}, key=10, data=4
2015-09-27 20:02:38 MainThread no worker threads
2015-09-27 20:02:38 MainThread done
```

Answer (score 1):

There can be different approaches based on the type of architecture and driver. One of them can be as below :

As soon as you receive data via receive interrupt, post the data to the main receive buffer queue. There can be a single thread called Rx dispatcher/Rx Manager that always reads the main receive buffer queue and post/dispatch to respective receive queue of reader threads based on msg type/id for further processing.

On the transmission side, respective thread can post the data along with msg type/id to the main transmit buffer queue which shall be sent out by Tx thread via transmit interrupt.

Comment: Your answer describes what [the code in my answer does](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32803324/4279). Have you expected that there should be a difference?

Comment: I did not check the python code as i am not aware of python so far. I proposed one of the very high level approach. However, if the approach mentioned in the code is same as the approach put forth by me, that's really great and we are inline on one of the approach.

Comment: *"Rx dispatcher"* is `reader` thread in my code (start at `def reader()` line). The controller is simulated using a dummy python subprocess and therefore *"main receive buffer queue"* is represented by  a `pipe` that is connected to subprocess' stdout. *"receive queue of reader threads"* is called `receive_queue` in `worker` threads and the corresponding collection  for all threads is called `thread_queues` in `reader` -- the responses from the controller are dispatched to `worker` threads based on [`key` field that identifies the request](http://goo.gl/JZ4mSn) (the thread that sent it)...

Comment: ...[continued]  *"transmission side"* / *"Tx thread"* is `writer` thread in the code and *"main transmit buffer queue"* is `send_queue` (`pipe` in `writer()` represents controller's stdin). The question has [tag:python-2.7] tag that is why I've used Python code for the answer.